# How to shrink JavaScript buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know you cannot trim it directly but is it the proper way to do:
convert buffer to string then trim then convert to buffer?
I'm using Node.js v.6.12.x

```
var buf = Buffer.alloc(xxxxxx);
.....
// buffer gets its value
.....

let buffParsed = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, buf);
buffParsed = buffParsed.replace(/\\"/g, '"');
console.log(buffParsed.length);

//now convert back to buffer... How?
//sorry for dummy question
```

Comment: `Buffer.from` perhaps?

Comment: You could use [`buf.slice(start, end)`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_slice_start_end)

Comment: i.,e. `let buffParsed = Buffer.from(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, buf).replace(/\\"/g, '"'));` - or more modern `let buffParsed = Buffer.from(String.fromCharCode(...buf).replace(/\\"/g, '"'));`

Comment: @JaromandaX Does it make sense to supply this answer as a comment? It seems useful

Comment: probably not, but I don't like posting answers using my phone - I always mess it up :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Buffer.from

```
var buf = Buffer.alloc(xxxxxx);
.....
// buffer gets its value
.....

let buffParsed = Buffer.from(String.fromCharCode(...buf).replace(/\\"/g, '"'));
```